# Regarding sorting of list without iterating

Tags: java

I have an array list , now i want to sort it , My arraylist contain duplicate elements too , that duplicate elements should also be removed in final outcome sorted list ,please advise

```
 ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
      list.add("Ram");
       list.add("Dinesh");
      list.add("Sachin");
      list.add("Dinesh");
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, if it is please edit the question to have the 'homework' tag.

Comment: @dbaupp, i DON'T HAVE THE IDEA,PLEASE ADVISE

Comment: Possible duplicate user: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1188021/neera

Comment: How can you possibly have a sorting algorithm without iterating over the data? Even if you use something like Collections.sort(), it'll still need to iterate over the data. If you add all items into a sorted correction that sorts as you add data, it is still performing comparisons to other items in the collection. Despite all this, you'll still need to iterate over the final sorted collection in order to get each of the items.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is not possible without some iteration but you don't have to do it yourself.
Try using a sorted set that sorts on insertion and also removes duplicates:

```
list = new ArrayList<String>( new TreeSet<String>(list) );
```

Basically you put the list content into a sorted set (a `TreeSet` in this case) and then copy the set's content back into a new list.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks a lot could you please provide a detailed example ...that will make understanding more clear..!!

Comment: @user1336909 my example should build on top of yours and contains everything you asked for. What more do you need?

Answer (score 0):

ditto on above. if you are sorting a collection of an object you created you will need to let Collections and Arrays know how to compare the objects.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class delme {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        SomeData[] theData = new SomeData[5];
        theData[0] = new SomeData("zzzz", 1);
        theData[1] = new SomeData("aaaa", 1);
        theData[2] = new SomeData("zzzz", 0);
        theData[3] = new SomeData("aaaa", 0);
        theData[4] = new SomeData("aaaa", 0);

        Arrays.sort(theData);

        for (int i = 0; i < theData.length; i++){
            System.out.println("theData[" + i + "]=" + theData[i].toString());
        }
    }
  }


  public class SomeData implements Comparable {

    public String someData1;
    public int someData2;


    public SomeData(String s, int i) {
        someData1 = s;
        someData2 = i;
    }


    //return -1 if this object should come before the arguments object in a sorted list
    //return 0 if they have the same value
    //return 1 if this object should come after in a sorted list
    public int compareTo(Object arg0) throws ClassCastException {
        if (!(arg0 instanceof SomeData)) //we must accept type Object so lets check to make sure its of type SomeData
            throw new ClassCastException("peram given is not a SomeData object");

        SomeData otherData = (SomeData)arg0; //lets cast it to our data type for ez access
        if (someData2 == otherData.someData2)
            return someData1.compareTo(otherData.someData1);
        return Integer.compare(someData2, otherData.someData2);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "someData1=" + someData1 + ", someData2=" + someData2;
    }
  }
```